# How can I get the real image value from each item in my list and subscribe it to another list?

Tags: html, angular

I have a list of services that have multiple property like serviceId, serviceName and photoProfile called from a database using a spring REST API.

The 'photoProfile' property only has the id of the profile picture which if you use the 'localhost:8082/downloadFile/'+photoProfile would get you the image which is in turn is stored in a folder in the spring project.

After looking for a while online, I've found how I can actually get the real image to display on my website but now I'm stuck since I need to do this for the whole list.

Here's my angular code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  services: any[] = [];
  imgSrc: any;
  newList: any[] = [];
  constructor(private router: Router, private service: UserService, private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getServices().subscribe(res => {
    this.services = res;
    console.log('services: ', this.services);
});
    for (let i = 0; i < this.services.length; i++) {
      const element = this.services[i];
      this.getImage('http://localhost:4200/downloadFile/' + element.photoProfile).subscribe(data => {
      this.createImageFromBlob(data);
    });
    this.newList.push(this.imgSrc);
    console.log(this.newList);
    //I want to add the element from the services list and the image value after being converted to the new list
    }
  }

  getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(imageUrl, {responseType: 'blob'});
  }

  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.imgSrc = reader.result;
    }, false);
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, can you explain the question. You are already pushing to the new list. So which list are you referring to when talking about whole list.

Comment: I have the services list which has all the services called from the database and the newList which has the same the properties as the services list plus the photo property which has the value of the converted picture. When i do the console.log(this.newList) nothing appears

Comment: oh ok. I posted the answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the new list inside the ngOnInit after you are subscribing to the services list. Because currently. You don't have the services when the for loop runs. You need to run the for loop after you have the result from services. Like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getServices().subscribe(res => {
    this.services = res;
    console.log('services: ', this.services);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.services.length; i++) {
      const element = this.services[i];
      this.getImage('http://localhost:4200/downloadFile/' + element.photoProfile).subscribe(data => {
        this.createImageFromBlob(data);
        element.imgSrc = this.imgSrc;
        this.newList.push(element);
       });
    console.log(this.newList);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But is there a way for the new list to get the object from the services list plus the photo?

Comment: Hi, yes. I edited the answer. We just need to add the imgSrc in the element and push it as a whole.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is too much but for some reason I keep getting undefined in every item of newList. I'm trying insert them each image as the background-image of a div with the info about the service so I used [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ s + ')'}" in my div but it didn't change and when I checked the console It showed me 'undefined' as the background-image

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that. It should be fixed now. Updated again.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation, and method of Muhammad Kamran work particularry for me, because images loaded into array absolutely randomly. As i understand, the speed of FOR cycle is faster than picture download speed. The solution is - pushing into array in createImageFromBlob (in case of i'mgnome). In my case it was like this:

```
export interface File {
...
original_name: name of file;
linkToPicture: string;
image: any;
}
...
files: File[] = [];//array for incoming data with link to pictures

this.getTable(...)
...
getTable(sendingQueryForm: QueryForm){
      this.queryFormService.getTable(sendingQueryForm)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
              this.files=data as File[]; 
              for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
                this.getImage('/api/auth/getFileImage/' + this.files[i].linkToPicture).subscribe(blob => {
                  this.createImageFromBlob(blob,i);
                });
              }
            },
            error => console.log(error) 
        );
    }

getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.http.get(imageUrl, {responseType: 'blob'});
}

createImageFromBlob(image: Blob, index:number) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
    this.files[index].image = reader.result;
  }, false);
  if (image) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let block of files; let i = index" >
    <mat-card class="grid-card">
        <div>
            <img [src]="block.image" width=120>
            <p>{{block.original_name}}</p>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

I hope it will useful for someone and thanks for topic!